# Deform using stickman instead of cage

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging

I'm having difficulty creating a cage mesh around my target mesh, for mesh-deforming. I could use an armature, but it does not give me quite the effect I want. Unless I'm mistaken, I cannot move armature joints in pose mode correct?

I've tried hook modifier as well, but my mesh is a bit too complex for that, it would require a lot of hooks to work.

Is there a way I could get the same effect/control as a cage mesh-deform, without the cage having to cover the target mesh?

Answer (score 1):

Others have provided potential solutions to your original problem, but neither answered the question of whether you need to cage to enclose the mesh.

The mesh deform modifier only works on vertices fully enclosed by the cage mesh. There are no alternatives to this currently in blender that allow you to get a similar effect without an enclosing cage.

Also worth noting is that using an armature with disconnected bones (as in [SVAFnemesis](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47042/26345)' answer) is just about functionally equivalent to deforming one mesh with another stick figure mesh (with the added advantages of weight painting and bone twisting).

Other potential solutions, depending on exactly what deformation you need, are the [lattice](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/lattice.html) and [curve](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/curve.html) modifers, but without knowing exactly what deformations you need, I can't say whether these would actually be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do, you can use an armature to achieve it.
Simply add bones without connected parenting to one and another (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> in armature edit mode). Then apply automatic weight. Related settings are under bone property tab.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the shape of your character, you could always duplicate the mesh you want to cage deform, scale it up a little, throw a decimate modifier on it to get lower polys, and then use that as your cage.  But its hard to see without seeing your .blend

Comment: possibly scaling along normals, using Alt-S, (Shrink/Fatten) ?

Answer (score 0):

You actually have a few options here.

For actually doing a mesh deform with a string of vertices, you can add a skin modifier to the string of verts (the deformer), then add both a mesh deform and a Laplacian deform modifier to the mesh being deformed.

Laplacian deform will basically fill in the positions of the verts that you didn't explicitly deform.  Laplacian deform requires a bit of setup, particular at mesh edges.  To make it follow your string, assign all the verts that end up getting mesh deformed, as well as all mesh edges, to an anchor vertex group for the Laplacian deform.  You can move this anchor closer to the deforming stick as you see fit.  You should check out the manual on Laplacian deform.

Another thing to try, to address your underlying issue but not necessarily to use a stick to deform a mesh, is to use a surface deform instead of a mesh deform.  A surface deformer does not need to be manifold and does not need to contain the verts it deforms.  But it *can* be manifold, if you want.  Just because it says "surface" doesn't mean you can't use it on something less flat :)